# Creating dynamic instance methods in after_save callback rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, metaprogramming

I have a `after_save` callback in a model named `Field` and i am creating dynamic instance methods in it on other model named `User`, but the code is not working, i am unable to figure out whats wrong with it, as the logic is very simple.Please help.

```
class field < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_create :create_user_methods

  private

    def create_user_methods
      User.class_eval do
        define_method(self.name) do
          #some code
        end

        define_method(self.name + "=") do
          #some code
        end
      end
    end

end
```

and then I am creating Field instance in `rails console` like this

```
  Field.create(name: "test_method")
```

And then calling that method on User class instance like this

```
  User.new.test_method
```

But it raises error

undefined method `test_method` for ....

Comment: The defined method will only be available in the same instance of the application. That means on a default production system with a puma or unicorn server with multiple workers and perhaps even multiple servers this will fail. Can you please explain, why you want to do that and what you try to achieve?

Comment: @spickermann its simple, i want to create methods on User class object as per the Field object name.

Comment: @spickermann, thanks for this comment, I haven't realized this before. In a system like this, it might be better to use `method_missing` in the User model that would grab all the currently defined fields (although the performance would hurt I guess).

Comment: Sure, I understand that. But why? Why do you think you need that?

Comment: @spickermann as the end user can create new `Field` objects at run time and i don't want to restart server, i have a loop defined in `User` model which creates methods corresponding to each existing `Field` object in the same way when server starts, but as @Borama suggested i can use method_missing here.

Comment: Sounds dangerous. What happens if someone defines a `Field` named `save`, `valid?` or `update`? `method_missing` seems the better way in this case.

Comment: @spickermann alright

Answer (score 0):

I got the fix, I can not use `self` inside the `class_eval` block as its value is User model not `Field` class object, therefore the fix is:

```
class field < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_create :create_user_methods

  private

    def create_user_methods

      name = self.name # here self points to field object

      User.class_eval do
        define_method(name) do
          #some code
        end

        define_method(name + "=") do
          #some code
        end
      end
    end
  end
```